# Comments on declined flags: thank you mods

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderators

I noticed over the last few months that some moderators add short comments when flags are declined.

This is a very good initiative as it often provides context on the thinking of the mods in taking their actions, and I would like to strongly encourage all moderators to continue in this direction.

Answer (score 4):

Since this a post about appreciating moderator feedback, I suppose it’s appropriate to reply (on behalf of the team) with “you’re welcome.”